# Django; limit Subcategory to a certain Main Category

Tags: python, django

I have a fairly simple question which I might be able to achieve by dynamically getting `CHOICES` by doing a query, but I was wondering if there's more "native" way to do this in Django;

Asume this;

```
class Item(models.Model):

    name = name = models.CharField(max_length = 75)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey('ItemSubcategory')
```

This would be an example of hierarchy;

- Category: Food

  - Subcategory: Bread

    - Item: Tiger Bread
    - Item: Brown Bread
    - Item: White Bread

This logic is ok, but for certain other Models I want to use it like this;

```
class Item(models.Model):

    name = name = models.CharField(max_length = 75)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey('ItemSubcategory', limit_to=('ItemCategory', 'Food'))
```

So it would limit the dropdown/filter I would use to only show Food Subcategories and not all other Subcategories that are under other Categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `limit_choices_to` argument: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to

```
class Item(models.Model):

    name = name = models.CharField(max_length = 75)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(
        'ItemSubcategory', 
        limit_choices_to={'ItemCategory': 'Food'}
    )
```

Just to give you the basic idea.

Comment: Almost, this worked; `limit_choices_to={'category__name': 'Food'}`. Thanks for the hint :)